# VBA Deleting Connections, "Assignment to constant not permitted" Error

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, excel-2016

I am attempting to delete duplicated queries using VBA. I used a similar macro to turn off the refresh on refresh all for specific connections but I seem to have issues with apply the same concept to deleting.

```
Sub DeleteConnections()
Dim cn As WorkbookConnection
Dim qr As WorkbookQuery
    For Each cn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        cn.Delete = CBool(cn.Name Like "BPTable(*" Or cn.Name Like "BPResourceChart(*" Or cn.Name Like "BPFlowSteps(*" _
            Or cn.Name Like "BPDayChart(*" Or cn.Name Like "BPResource(*" Or cn.Name Like "BPTable2(*" _
            Or cn.Name Like "BPHistoric(*" Or cn.Name Like "BPHistoryHours(*")
    Next
    For Each qr In ActiveWorkbook.Queries
        qr.Delete = CBool(qr.Name Like "BPTable(*" Or qr.Name Like "BPResourceChart(*" Or qr.Name Like "BPFlowSteps(*" _
            Or qr.Name Like "BPDayChart(*" Or qr.Name Like "BPResource(*" Or qr.Name Like "BPTable2(*" _
            Or qr.Name Like "BPHistoric(*" Or qr.Name Like "BPHistoryHours(*")
    Next
End Sub
```

Stop Refresh on Refresh All:

```
Sub RefreshAllBlock()
 Dim conn As Object
    For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        conn.RefreshWithRefreshAll = Not CBool(conn.Name Like "*BP*" Or conn.Name Like "*ProductionSupportTickets*")
    Next
End Sub
```

**Full Code Solution Thanks to BigBen:**

```
Sub DeleteConnections()
Dim cn As WorkbookConnection
Dim qr As WorkbookQuery
    For Each cn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        If cn.Name Like "*BPTable (*" Or cn.Name Like "*BPResourceChart (*" Or cn.Name Like "*BPFlowSteps (*" _
            Or cn.Name Like "*BPDayChart (*" Or cn.Name Like "*BPResource (*" Or cn.Name Like "*BPTable2 (*" _
            Or cn.Name Like "*BPHistoric (*" Or cn.Name Like "*BPHistoryHours (*" Then
        cn.Delete
        End If
        Next
    For Each qr In ActiveWorkbook.Queries
        If qr.Name Like "BPTable (*" Or qr.Name Like "BPResourceChart (*" Or qr.Name Like "BPFlowSteps (*" _
            Or qr.Name Like "BPDayChart (*" Or qr.Name Like "BPResource (*" Or qr.Name Like "BPTable2 (*" _
            Or qr.Name Like "BPHistoric (*" Or qr.Name Like "BPHistoryHours (*" Then
        qr.Delete
        End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing methods and properties.

[`WorkbookConnection.Delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbookconnection.delete) and [`WorkbookQuery.Delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbookquery.delete) are methods that are called; one cannot assign a boolean like you're attempting to.

By contrast, [`WorkbookConnection.RefreshWithRefreshAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbookconnection.refreshwithrefreshall) is  a property that can be changed.<sup>1</sup>

Change

```
cn.Delete = ....
```

to

```
If cn.Name Like "BPTable(" Or cn.Name Like "BPResourceChart(*" Or cn.Name Like "BPFlowSteps(" _
            Or cn.Name Like "BPDayChart(*" Or cn.Name Like "BPResource(*" Or cn.Name Like "BPTable2(*" _
            Or cn.Name Like "BPHistoric(*" Or cn.Name Like "BPHistoryHours(*)" Then
    cn.Delete
End If
```

and similarly for the queries.

<sup>1</sup> Note that properties can be read-only. As noted in the docs, `RefreshWithRefreshAll` is Read/Write.